# Please blacklist the [garden] tag as intrinsic

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

Over two years ago, I asked [Should we blacklist the [garden] tag?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/640/should-we-blacklist-the-garden-tag) and got an answer saying "yes", with no dissent. I argued then that it counts as an intrinsic tag,

> one that is so general that it could be applied to most or all questions on a site.

At that time, we got rid of the [garden](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garden) tag and I thought no more of it. However, starting in May 2016, it started to creep back in, and after three questions using it in the last half of 2016, we've had 21 (mostly by new or lower-rep users) in the first half of 2017.

I've just removed it again from all questions that used it. Since it has reappeared at least once, could it be blacklisted so that it can never be used again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done.

I marked it as an "intrinsic" tag - that is, a tag that is considered to apply to every question asked here. As such, it cannot be used here but won't block migrations from other sites.

Comment: Thanks Shog9. This greatly improves the site, and makes life easier for the editors. There have been times in the past when I wasn't sure whether or not to remove the tag during the editing process. Now I won't have to think about it anymore. We appreciate your help, and the speed at which you took care of this!